# pgAdmin 4 v2.1 download - could not verify .sig file

Tags: pgadmin-4

I downloaded the installer and .sig file for the latest pgAdmin 4 v2.1 from [their website](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.1/windows/), given the recent malware/security issues I thought best to verify the installer using Kleopatra (part of [Gpg4win](https://www.gpg4win.org/)) before doing anything, but got this message:

[image: verification_failed]

I have emailed the maintainer as listed on the download page but yet to hear back from him. Does anyone know if this is a cause for concern? I will update this post if/when I hear back from the maintainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works now after the maintainer sent me his public key, which I had to certify first, once that was all set up I was able to verify the .sig file.